# CSS: Why is my form submit button on a new line?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

On my web site, http://tinyurl.com/yhvj6g

Why is it that Internet Explorer is placing my "Find listing" submit button on a new line whereas Firefox & Chrome keep the submit button inline horizontally with the input field (which is the desired result)?

I would like Internet Explorer to behave the same as Firefox & Chrome in that it keeps the "Find Listings" submit button horizontally inline with the input field.

I assume this is a CSS issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: FYI: this looks fine in IE8; but yes, it's wrong in IE7

Comment: could it be that there's not enough room for it on the same line as the textbox (given the width constraint)?

Comment: A *lot* of people would like Internet Explorer to behave the same as Firefox & Chrome. It would simplify the job of creating webpages.

Comment: @Michael, any suggestion as to what I can do to make this work in IE 6/7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting width on that button so that textbox + button + padding < 400px (size of your container).  Seems to me that the button slips to the second line simply because it's too wide to fit on the same line

Answer (score 1):

Looking at both, the button is significantly wider in IE than in Firefox.  I'd guess that it's too wide to fit in the available space on IE, and is getting moved to the next "line".  Try reducing the padding to 0 on the button and see what happens; also, you might put the form inside an explicitly-sized div to force enough room.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My FORM width was not wide enough